# How do I get notification to my phone, when my PC starts?

Tags: windows, remote-access

I want to know how can I get notification to my phone when my PC goes online *(Turns On)*.

Comment: A windows service or scheduled task that when started sends a push notification. On the iPhone develop an app that receives the notifications. Hard to get provide more info without a [mcve]

Comment: What does *"my PC goes online"* mean?

Comment: @IInspectable - when my pc starts

Comment: Use the [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) to set up a scheduled task, that pushes a notification to your phone when the system is booted. This doesn't appear to be a programming question, though.

Answer (score 0):

TeamViewer can help you: https://www.teamviewer.com.

If you install this app on your pc and you sync your user on your iPhone, I guess that whenever your pc starts you will get a notification

Answer (score 0):

If your pc have login in, you can create an powershell script for any time when some one login in your pc you receive an email. Or, this is hard, you can creat an powershell script for when an service start on your pc, send you an email too, you set the service on the start.

```
$filter="*[System[EventID=7036] and EventData[Data='SIOS DataKeeper']]"
$A = Get-WinEvent -LogName System -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXPath $filter
$Message = $A.Message
$EventID = $A.Id
$MachineName = $A.MachineName
$Source = $A.ProviderName

$EmailFrom = "sios@medfordband.com"
$EmailTo = "sios@medfordband.com"
$Subject ="Alert From $MachineName"
$Body = "EventID: $EventID`nSource: $Source`nMachineName: $MachineName `n$Message"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("sios@medfordband.com", "MySMTPP@55w0rd");
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

Like this, the event is the SIOS DataKeeper, when someone start the service you will receive an email. You can set the service for windows start, when the windows start you will receive an email.